# how to retrive Spatia media collection in custom resource in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-medialibrary

i am using Spatie media package in laravel, when i try to display media in Spatie collection is show defualt data from package .

Controller :

```
 public function index(IndexTicketRequest $request)
{
    $tickets = Ticket::query()->with(['employee','media']);

    if ($request->has('status')) {
        $tickets->where('status', $request->get('status'));
    }

    return TicketResource::collection($tickets->orderByDesc('created_at')->paginate($request->per_page ?? 20));
}
```

Resource:

```
 public function toArray($request)
{

    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'category' => $this->category,
        'fullname' => $this->fullname,
        'username' => $this->username,
        'file' => $this->file,
        'message' => $this->message,
        'status' => TicketType::getDescription($this->status),
        'employee' => $this->whenLoaded('employee'),
        'media' => $this->whenLoaded('media'),
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple to load media with collections. You just need to add with function before paginate(ex: `with(['media'])` ). please follow the modificaitons:

```
    public function index(IndexTicketRequest $request)
    {
        $tickets = Ticket::query()->with(['employee','media']);

        if ($request->has('status')) {
            $tickets->where('status', $request->get('status'));
        }

        return TicketResource::collection($tickets->orderByDesc('created_at')->with(['media'])->paginate($request->per_page ?? 20));
    }
```